# Get state of all links in a model in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I can get a list of all link states in gazebo by calling

```
rostopic echo -n 1 /gazebo/link_states
```

But what about getting link states for only a specific model I'm interested in?

Also, what is the syntax for specifying a link name? I used

```
 rosservice call gazebo/get_link_properties '{link_name: link1}'
```

but got an error instead. Is there a way for me to specify the robot name as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30803/get-state-of-all-links-in-a-model-in-gazebo?/) by [wennho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2081/wennho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct sintax to get the state of the link you are interested on is:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/get_link_state 'link_name: MODEL_NAME::LINK_NAME'
```

Link names are prefixed by model name, e.g. pr2::base_link.

The same for the second command, the correct sintax is:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/get_link_properties 'link_name: MODEL_NAME::LINK_NAME'
```

---

Originally posted by [Giacomo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4000/giacomo/) with karma: 36 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giacomo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4000/giacomo/) on 2013-03-06**:
I forgot one important thing: the link has to be the root link of the robot.